# MongoDB indexes are not working when querying with $facet

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate, facet

I have index on the *status* key in the *example* collection.
This is the aggregate query I make:

```
db.getCollection('example').aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            Active: [
                {
                    $match: {
    
                            status: "OK"
                    }
                }
            ]
       }
   }
])
```

this query takes above to 10s to return.
If I do the same query using find, instead of aggregate, the query will return in 0.003 ms.
As I mentioned there is index on *status* key.

What am I missing in here?

Comment: If you do a `find` you will get just the first few matching documents (and can iterate for more). That will be very fast. Your aggregation returns one huge document with an array containing all matching documents. That has to read through the whole collection.

Comment: Even when adding `$skip:0` and `$limit: 10` it still takes 10s...

Comment: What does "explain" say?

Comment: Docs examined about 90k, stage is COLLSCAN, totalKeysExamined: 0 and totalDocsExamined: 90k, executionTimeMills 10s approx, is there something specific to look on?

Comment: If there is a common filter that is shared by all your facets, you could pull out the `$match` for that into an earlier pipeline stage. Otherwise MongoDB will have to figure this out itself, which may be a bit too much for it.

Comment: I have ran this query command in the Robo 3t (just like mongo shell) without any stages in the $facet, only this one to test this out.. also put the $match stage before the $facet but this ain't working. Note that when I query using $or operator it even takes much more time, while in the find method it takes really 0s anyway

Comment: `$match` in the first stage still does not use the index? That is odd...

Comment: no, my mistake - when adding the match earlier than the $facet the query takes 0s. But how can I put the $match before the $facet? I actually have multiple $match(es)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221571/discussion-between-raz-and-thilo).

Answer (score 1):

A MongoDB aggregation operates as a pipeline, documents are read from the named collection at the start of the pipeline, matched and/or mutated as by each stage, and then passed along to the next stage.

A [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html#facet-aggregation) stage, every document that is passed to the stage is forwarded to *each* facet.

In the case of your pipeline, the aggregation will read **all** of the documents from the collection, and pass them in their entirety to the `Active` facet where the `$match` stage will dutifully examine each one.

When the aggregation pipeline begins with a stage that filters, like `$match` or `$geoNear`, it will use an index to select matching documents from the collection, greatly reducing the number of documents that enter the pipeline.